# Error al cargar archivos al servidor usando Web API's

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

Estoy realizando una aplicación web simple para subir un archivo al servidor. He usado **Jquery** y **AJAX** para el código del lado del cliente y **C#** para el lado del servicio.

Al momento de cargar el archivo obtengo el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El siguiente es el controlador para cargar mis archivos en una carpeta:

```
public class FileUploadController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public string[] UploadFiles()
        {
            HttpFileCollection files = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;
            string[] path = new string[files.Count];
            for(var i = 0;i < files.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpPostedFile file = files[i];
                string roothPath = "~/Upload/" + file.FileName;

                path[i] = roothPath.Substring(1);
                file.SaveAs(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(roothPath));
            }

            return path;
        }
    }
```

La siguiente es mi función de JQuery para cargar archivos:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#fileUpload").on("change", function () {
                var files = $(this).get(0).files;
                var formData = new FormData();
                for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    formData.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
                }
                uploadFiles(formData);
            })
        })

        function uploadFiles(formData) {
            $.ajax({
                url:"api/FileUpload/UploadFiles",
                method:"POST",
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert("Upload Failed!");
                }
            })
        }
```

El siguiente es parte de mi formulario en HTML el cual carga el archivo:

```
<div class="form-group">
                            <label for="fileUpload">Adjunta tu CV:</label>
                            <input type="file" id="fileUpload" class="btn" accept=".pdf" />
                        </div>
```

**Actualización:**

Imprimiendo el error en consola de la siguiente manera `console.error(error);` se muestra lo siguiente:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: error is not defined
    at Object.error (detalle.html?vacante=5637146081:483)
    at u (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Comment: en la funcion error: function (data) { implrime que esta sucendiendo que error regresa.

Comment: @MiguelZarate puedes revisar mi ultima actualización allí coloque el error que me muestra en consola

Comment: error: function (data, status) {
                    console.log(data)
console.log(status)
                }

Comment: debes poner ```console.error(data)``` al capturar el error